# Encoding error when saving a document through a rake task on rails

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, encoding

I have a rake task that downloads an XML document through HTTP and writes it to file. The XML downloaded has a rather nasty encoding, but it's encoded as 8-bit ASCII with a code page "windows-1254" on the XML.

```
url = URI("http://report.paragaranti.com/rasyonet_xml_fund_data.asp")
http = Net::HTTP.new url.host
http.read_timeout = 120
response = http.get url.path
response.error! unless response.instance_of? Net::HTTPOK
filename = "#{Date.today}.xml"
File.open(filename, 'w') {|f| f.write(response.body)}
```

The code above works when I'm executing it as a simple script with no errors. However when I do the same thing through as a rake task through rails I get the following exception:

```
"\xF0" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8
```

It must be something to do with the encoding of the string, but I'm not sure why it happens or why the code has different behavior in a rails environment and outside it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to resolve the problem by doing:

```
File.open(filename, 'wb') {|f| f.write(response.body)}
```

That is, writing the file as **binary**. Still, an explanation of what's going on here would be much appreciated (especially the part about why it does not work in a rails environment..)